# Generate a "Logout" link in Concrete 5.7

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I want to create a <kbd>Logout</kbd> link in my Concrete 5.7 theme.

What function do I call to generate that URL, seeing as it contains special security tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should generate a logout URL:

```
URL::to('/login', 'logout', \Core::make('helper/validation/token')->generate('logout'));
```

If you only want to show it when the user is actually logged in, you can combine it with this `if` statement:

```
if (!(new User())->isLoggedIn()) {
    $url = URL::to('/login');
} else {
    $url = URL::to('/login', 'logout', 
                   \Core::make('helper/validation/token')->generate('logout'));
}
```

Comment: Corrected my example, thanks to suggestion by @mnkras

Answer (score 2):

In 5.7+ you should no longer use `Loader`, it should all use `Core::make()` so we can take the code from @simon-east and change it like so:

```
if (!(new User())->isLoggedIn()) {
    $url = URL::to('/login');
} else {
    $url = URL::to('/login', 'logout', \Core::make('helper/validation/token')->generate('logout'));
}
```